# django - TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, django

I am working through this [Getting started with Django Rest Framework by Building a Simple Product Inventory Manager](https://www.techiediaries.com/tutorial-django-rest-framework-building-products-manager-api/) tutorial. At the end the tutorial, it says that I "should now be able to run your server and start playing with diffrent API endpoints". However, when I run the server, all I'm getting is a TemplateDoesNotExist error. At no point in the tutorial does it mention creating templates (and this is eventually going to connect to an Angular 2 frontend, as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-angular-cli/)), so I'm confused at to whether this is an error in my code, or if the tutorial left a step out. I do not get any console errors when I run my code.

*serializers.py*

```
from .models import Product, Family, Location, Transaction
from rest_framework import serializers

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ('reference', 'title', 'description')

class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Family
    fields = ('reference', 'title', 'description', 'unit', 'minQuantity')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('sku', 'barcode', 'title', 'description', 'location', 'family')
    depth = 1

class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  product = ProductSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    fields = ('sku', 'barcode', 'product')
```

*views.py*

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import status, generics, mixins
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Product, Location, Family, Transaction
from .serializers import *

# Create your views here.

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def product_list(request):
    """
    List all products, or create a new product.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products,context={'request': request} ,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def product_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a product instance.
    """
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product,context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product, data=request.data,context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        product.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class family_list(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

class family_detail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

class location_list(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer

class location_detail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    serializer_class =  LocationSerializer

class transaction_list(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer

class transaction_detail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class =  TransactionSerializer
```

IF you need to see more of my code, please comment and I'll post it, but everything should be identical to the code given in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you forgot to add `rest_framework` in [the installed apps](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation)(settings.py).

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rest_framework',
)
```

Comment: That changed the error I'm getting, at least. Now it says "OperationalError at /products/ no such table: inventory_product". I think this just means I need to add data to the table?

Comment: No. You have make the tables first at the database level.

Comment: Use "python manage.py makemigrations" and "python manage.py migrate"

Comment: Gotcha. I thought I'd already done that, but I guess I hadn't. Thank you

Comment: You are Welcome. :)